# Finding the nth term of large Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

I have to write a program where I am given the last three digits of an nth term. For Example, the 20th term is 6765 and the last three digits are '765'. Now I need to find the 1st digit of the Fibonacci sequence which has '321' as the last three digits.

I looked online and found that the nth term is 479 and the program I wrote cannot even go that high. I could not find anyone that has a program that goes higher than the 100th term either.

As of right now is their no way to find a term higher than 100? 
Any other ideas you guys have other than recursion to find the first digit of the number ending with '321'?

My recursion code is pretty basic:

```
long long fibNum(long long nth)
{
    if (nth == 1)
        return 1;
    else if (nth == 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibNum(nth - 1) + fibNum(nth - 2);
}
```

By the time I get to the 43th term it begins to slow down.

Comment: Rewrite without recursion. That is what is slowing things down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 479th number is
    5696323922575865414847061494575945648081290145228607189038829076215134884313127297923138542545712321

that will not fit even in a long long variable. I suggest you to implement it taking in consideration just the lowest part of the number. You don't need to store the complete number just to calculate the last 3 digits, and then approximate the whole number.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PHI 1.61803399

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pos;
    int x = 0, y = 1, tmp = 0;
    long double num=0;

    int searched = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("Looking for a fibonacci number ending with: %03d\n", searched);

    for(pos = 2; y != searched; pos++){
        tmp = x+y;
        x = y;
        y = tmp%1000;
    }

    pos--;
    printf("Found at position: %d\n", pos);

    num = (powl(PHI, pos) - powl(1-PHI, pos))/sqrt(5);
    printf("Approximated number %Le\n", num);

    while(num >= 10) num /= 10;

    printf("First digit: %d\n", (int)num);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
> ./finbonacci 321
Looking for a fibonacci number ending with: 321
Found at position: 479
Approximated number 5.696326e+99
First digit: 5
```

This code first calculate the position of the number we are looking for in the sequence, than uses the [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence) that can approximate the nth number of the Fibonacci sequence. Since we need just the first digit, we can tolerate the approximation error.

Comment: I get how it finds the nth term but I dont think it finds the first digit of that sequence, which is another thing I need to find